# File Attachment inside P4 Changelists

Tags: perforce, attachment, changelist

I'm looking for a way to embed file attachments (like screenshots) inside a Perforce changelist. I'm hoping (but not optimistic) that there's a way inside P4 to actually do this, possibly via a plugin.

If not, I'll either have to look into writing a plugin myself (any pointers?), or I have to cook up a wrapper for P4 checkins that also uploads/submits the attachment, then links that attachment to the CL via an identifier inside the CL. (And then I need a tool to correlate and display both).

To add a bit more information: I'm interfacing with the P4 server via a P4API bot that I'm writing. That bots crawls over every checkin and harvests the data it gets to generate reports. I.e. it correlates submissions with the actual feature spec that informed the task, generates a history of progress for that task etc. Within that context, attaching additional meta data to a CL (like a screenshot) is useful because those attachments can then be used in the data mining - they can enhance the reports that I'm generating. 
I can guard against bad/rampant metadata attachments via a wrapper program that is used to make 95% of all our P4 submissions, anyway (it has its own dialog). But I gotta figure out how to present all the data inside P4 when the P4 CL spec only seems to have text available.

Comment: The only problem I see with this question is that it is borderline off-topic for two reasons: "possibly via a plugin" makes it sound like an off-site resource request, and asking generally for "any pointers" about writing a plugin make it sound too broad. I would edit it down so it just describes what you're trying to do and asks how to do it. List any resources you've consulted and research you've done to try to solve it.

Comment: Could you explain what you need that you can't get by "p4 add"ing the file to the changelist before submit?  Is it that you want to do this after submit, or is it that you want the attachment to show up in a particular interface in a particular way (if so you should say which and how), or what?

Comment: Hmm! Actually adding the file to the same CL is one of those obvious approaches that nobody's simply thought of yet! We might actually be able to do that and skirt around the whole issue.

Comment: @Drakestar Do you really want to have random screenshots, binary blobs, text files, and other things scattered around your source tree? I don't think you want to start adding "attachments" to the changelists themselves. It's going to make your source tree a mess. Even if you designate a specific folder for containing "attachments", it's still odd - you shouldn't be putting changelist metadata under revision control itself. Your tree will grow in disk size unnecessarily, making retrieve operations slower, and making merges, development streams, and branches more difficult to manage.

Comment: See above. I hear your concern. I'm also confident that we can guard against this via our submission wrapper, tho, and that the extra metadata this would add is a drop in a bucket compared to the amount of project data that's being generated anyway.

Comment: I have many thoughts on this (and easy solutions to the above concerns) but stackoverflow frowns on discussion in these comment threads so I suggest starting a thread on forums.perforce.com  :)

Comment: @Drakestar It sounds like you have pretty extensive data analysis requirements. I can appreciate the simplicity of just putting the meta-files in the changelists, but I would still caution against it. You say you're already generating a huge amount of project data. Is this existing data also being added to the source tree? If so, maybe this new requirement can be the impetus to change a currently less-than optimal process. It sounds like you should set up a proper database to manage all this data rather than trying to pigeonhole P4 into a task it's not designed to do.

Comment: @SamStafford You could also open a chat room here. =) I'd be interested in hearing your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any (easy) way to do what you're requesting. A [changelist](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/p4eclipse/topics/glossary.html) is "an atomic change transaction". There is very little meta-data with them. The [P4 command reference for p4 change](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_change.html) lists everything you're allowed to do, and adding an arbitrary attachment isn't there.

You could always open a feature request in the [Perforce forums](http://forums.perforce.com/).

**In Response to Edits**

It looks like this is actually just one instance of a larger problem you're facing: managing meta-data around your depot's projects and its changelists. I would suggest you use this requirement as a driving force behind making some larger process changes at your organization. If you have a lot of data being generated based on automated analysis of your projects, it would be better to create a proper database to organize it all. Your submission wrapper could handle putting screenshots (or any other meta data) in a database and annotating the change list description with tags that indicate where to find attachments in the database.

A comprehensive database solution would allow you to associate attachments, changelists and other data with each other and other project resources in a more organized fashion than you currently have.

**Original Response**

If you decide to write a plugin to handle just this task without a database, my suggested approach would be the following:

1. Designate a shared network drive or directory that is accessible to all team members as the "perforce attachment dump". Users should have write access to this area.
2. Use the changelist description field to create a tag to name a file that should be attached. For example, "Attach: file_name.jpg".
3. Your users use the plugin to navigate to the file(s) locally and the plugin will copy it to the dump drive and add the tag to the description. The plugin should enforce some naming scheme to make the files easy to find. Perhaps append the changelist number to the file base name? Or create a folder for each changelist?
4. Use a server side pre-submit trigger and script to scan submitted changelist descriptions for tags and retrieve this file from the attachment dump. It should probably reject changelists with the tag if it can't find the file.
5. The server side script should move the file to a share drive that is *read-only* to users. This is so that if you want to look at an attachment for a changelist that is five months old, you can be sure it will still be available.
6. Give your plugin the ability to open the attachments on the read-only share drive from your developer's local machines, from within P4 and P4V.

Comment: Marking this one as correct right now even if it doesn't necessarily solve my problem. But that's just because P4 doesn't have a clear solution. Gonna move this to the P4 forums (eventually) after looking into the simple attachment approach.

Comment: @Drakestar Can you provide a link to the forum discussion after you opening it? I'll add it to my answer.